# Install Kivy on Ubuntu 18.04. not working

Tags: python, python3, pip, kivy

I'm trying to install Kivy, a Python Framework, but run into problems using pip.

Following the instructions on https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-linux.html
I get the following error.

Can someone help? What Input should I post here to resolve the issue?

```
$ python -m pip install --upgrade --user pip setuptools virtualenv
```

---

```
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/setuptools/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Collecting virtualenv
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenv (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for virtualenv
```

--- Details ---
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS "bionic"

Answer (score 0):

Install openssl package.

```
sudo apt install openssl
```

This should do it.If not fixed and if you are using python3 then you may install:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Then try this:

```
pip3 install setuptools vurtualenv
```

Comment: openssl is already the newest version (1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.6) AND
python3-pip is already the newest version (9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.1). AND

Comment: pip3 install setuptools virtualenv --> Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping

Comment: Unfortunately no success:

Comment: Then you can look up in StackOverflow.I had this problem once and installed openssl.That solved the issue.